# SonarQube: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube.(csproj)

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to use the sonar-scanner-for-msbuild-2.0 for C# on Jenkins to analyze my projects.

But I have some errors :

> C:\Jenkins\workspace\365view - COMMON - Sonar Connector CSharp
>   SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild End Step 2.0
>   WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: C:\Windows\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: C:\Jenkins\workspace\365view - COMMON - Sonar Connector CSharp\365.connector.dto\365.connector.dto.csproj
>   WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: C:\Windows\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: C:\Jenkins\workspace\365view - COMMON - Sonar Connector CSharp\365.connector.library\365.connector.library.csproj
>   WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: C:\Windows\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: C:\Jenkins\workspace\365view - COMMON - Sonar Connector CSharp\365.connector.server.api\365.connector.server.api.csproj
>   15:46:40.296  Creating a summary markdown file...
>   Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
>   ERROR: Execution of MSBuild SonarQube Runner failed (exit code 1)
>   Blockquote

I had some problems before because I was using an AssemblyInfo.cs shared file so I removed it. But I still have some errors, this time on my csproj, 'm using shared files in my csproj too, can it be the problem too ?

IS there a way to have a more explicit error ?